# Select * from the table name returned from $q = intval($_GET['q']);

Tags: php, mysql, sql, environment-variables, ajaxform

I may be doing this the hard way, but I have 2 tables, one of them lists categories with an ID given to each, and each individual category table of its own is named the id, so with a GET request, I'm trying to pull the data using Ajax, PHP, and MySQLi. I've got it figured out, except for calling the variable in the table name. I kinda suck at explaining, so let me mumble along with my code.

The category table is laid out in a selection box with the ID value given to the option, and passed along to the 2nd php page, getcat.php?q=cat_name, for example. I bring q into getcat.php using simply.

```
$q = intval($_GET['q']);
```

Obviously SELECT * FROM $q would be too easy, so I've been trying this, but am not sure how to parse it into PHP, or really use it.

```
 <?php
 $q = intval($_GET['q']);

  $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','maindb');
 if (!$con) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
 }
```

This works fine.

But after that I have no clue. I tried this, but no luck.

```
 SET @cname:=intval($_GET['q']);

  SET @sql_text = concat('select * from (''%',@cname,'%'') where id = ?');

 PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

I've tried running queries in PhpMyAdmin, but no luck either. Completely stuck. I've tried DELIMITER, pretty much everything I've searched for, but I'll face it, I'm lost.

All help is appreciated. Thank you kindly.

Comment: "_and each individual category table of its own is named the id_" Are you saying you have a table for each category? Like a table `1`, table `2` etc.? (That sounds like bad db-design)

Comment: They're named in text abbreviations, but suggestions are welcome if you have any. There will be a lot of data, and I have it linking back and forth with parent and child ID's as well. I'm not too far into it yet, so suggestions are gratefully appreciated.It's been a while. I needed a project over quarantine. Thank you kindly.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You should look into [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for data fetching in PHP.

Comment: I've been looking into prepared statements, but am not understanding them, but will take a break and jump back in. I'm trying to pass a variable as a table name in a query (SELECT * FROM $variable_that_is_also_table_name). I'll look into your link, though, thank you!

Comment: Personally I wouldn't choose "dynamic" table names, too much of a hassle. You can reference any category via its `id`. Also, I might have been mislead/confused by your `$q = intval($_GET['q']);`: `intval()` returns an _integer_ value of a variable, but you've said "_They're named in text abbreviations_", that might be why you don't get the results you want. If you call something like `getcat.php?q=homeoffice` this'll return `0`, not `homeoffice`